# GNOME Characters 3.28.2

Tags: gnome, fonts, special-characters

How can one use the character map application that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 to browse Unicode blocks by script?

And how to make it display non-latin characters?
I selected "letters" from the left-hand tabs and select an Arabic font (the free Amiri font that comes by default with Ubuntu and that supports Unicode) but still all the characters displayed are Latin!

It seems that in trying to gear the application towards emojis all else was shoveled away!

Comment: Please note that the `gucharmap` program can be used as a supplement to `gnome-characters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing [as Gunnar Hjalmarsson advised](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111913/gnome-characters-3-28-2?noredirect=1#comment1835660_1111913) in his comment to my question: installing `gucharmap` and using that.
I still think that for the polyglot user this functionality should be made accessible by default in Ubuntu.